# Can you be issued an emergency American passport with a one way ticket?

Tags: passports

Will an American passport agency issue a passport with just a one way ticket?

Comment: Passports do not require any tickets for issuance. You only need to prove that you are a citizen of the country. Are you asking about visas which are required by people who are not US citizens to visit US?

Comment: @RedBaron Getting an appointment at a US passport agency does require proof of [a life-or-death emergency or urgent non-emergency travel](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast/passport-agencies.html). The question is reasonable.

Comment: @mlc Thanks. I was not aware of this.

Comment: The rules state "Get proof that you are traveling internationally in the next 72 hours (3 business days) such as an itinerary or airline ticket." This suggests they do not specifically require a return ticket, but hopefully someone knows more. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast/emergencies.html

Comment: Emergency passport are for emergencies. Try the conventional way. There are some tricks to get it issued sooner (which requires some extra expenses, e.g. finding the right place which can deliver it soon, and that you can take it in person).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the only way to choose where to apply for a US passport, and the only way to pick it up in person, is to use the emergency service or the 72-hour in-person service, both of which require proof of travel within 72 hours.  The normal service and the non-emergency expedited service are handled entirely by mail.

Comment: @phoog: usually, but some passport services allows some exceptions.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi if you have an authoritative source for that claim, you should post it in an answer.

Comment: @phoog: no, and I think there is no authoritative sources. I just say that googling to find which center makes exceptions (and I do not want to link directly not to cause troubles, or someone will try to block such exceptions). Travel would be much easier if every office will use the same (and documented) rules!

Answer (score 3):

> Will an American passport agency issue a passport with just a one way ticket?

Yes.  To get a passport using the in-person service, you need to show proof that you are traveling internationally in the next 72 hours.  (If your trip requires a visa, you can use the in-person service up to 10 days before your trip.)  A one-way ticket is just as much proof of that as is a round-trip ticket.

Details are available at https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast.html.